# Invoice Pdf for arabic order is not printing correct letters in magento

Tags: php, magento

Invoice Pdf for arabic order is not printing correct letters in magento.It is printing ******* for arabic letters.Please suggest solution for this

Answer (score 0):

```
    $page = $pdf->newPage(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
    $pdf->pages[] = $page;
    $this->_setFontRegular($page,12);
    $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.4, 0.4, 0.4));
    $page->drawText('Text', 15, $this->y, 'CP1256');
```

Try this.